# Why is 'void' used and not a specific data type as argument for a function in C++ using a class object array?

Tags: c++, object, parameters

Why are we giving *void* as a parameter for the *getdetails* function, i.e, *getdetails(void)* and not *(char name, int rollNO)* as a parameter? Why is this being done only while using array of class objects. Why?

```
class student
{
    private:
    char name[30];
    int rollNo;
    public:
    void getDetails(void); // Member function to get student's details
    void putDetails(void); // Member function to print student's details
};

void student::getDetails(void) // Member function definition, outside of the class
{
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter roll number: ";
    cin >> rollNo;
}
```

Comment: Because whoever wrote that probably spent a long time writing old C code, where this is common, but in C++ this doesn't mean anything. Further evidence of that is `char name[30];`, instead of `std::string`.

Comment: `some_function (void)` is just another way to write `some_function()`

Comment: @Miguel -- that's not quite right. You're right that as a function **declaration** or **definition** they're the same. That is, `int f() {}` and `int f(void) {}` mean the same thing. But when **calling** the function they're not the same. `f(void)` isn't legal.

Comment: @PeteBecker You are right, I meant in declarations. I should've specified.

Comment: @Miguel -- I figured that was what you meant. Just wanted to underscore it.